# Angular Project background image hide from the style.css class

Tags: html, css, angular

CSS and HTML.

I got below issue .

In the Angular project I have `home.component.html` like below:

```
    <div id="homecontent">
    <div class="imageslide">
        <ng-image-slider [images]="imageObject" [imageSize]="{width: '20%', height: '30%', space: 3}" #nav></ng-image-slider>
    </div>

    <div id="siteDesc">
        <h2>H test</h2>

    </div>
    <div class="left"> 
        <p>
            Some text
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

My `home.component.css` is as below

```
#homecontent{
  background-image: url(/assets/images/pagebackgorund.jpg);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

left{
float: left;
}
```

Now my question is the image I set in `#homecontent` is reset in the `.left` class div. How can I avoid it?

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "is reset in the .left class div"? Can you provide some screenshots?

Answer (score -1):

```
.left {
   float: left;
   clear:left;
}
```

clear: left will not override any relative elements in left. it will float left till it have space as soon as any element will be encountered, it will stop there.

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the questions. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, more useful for future visitors, and more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel updated above. actually forgot to add it. thanks.